# How to send firebase (fcm) to multiple users and different data per user

Tags: php, android, firebase, webview, firebase-cloud-messaging

i want to send fcm to multiple users but i want to send different data to each user , like this.

```
$deviceid2 ="da10bCm38LU:APA91bHC-XB";
$deviceid1 = "dKF-20xsI9Y:APA91bE";
$API_ACCESS_KEY='AAAA_';
$registrationIds = array( "$deviceid1","$deviceid2" );
$title1="title1";
$title2="title2";
$message1="message1";
$message2="message2";
$title = array( "$title1","$title2" );
$body = array( "$message1","$message2" );
$fields = array
(
'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
'data'   => array(

                'title'     => $title,
                'body'      => $body
)
);

$headers = array

(
'Authorization: key='.$API_ACCESS_KEY,
'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
```

i tried it,the response was success from curl, but no notification appeared on my phone. can anyone help for this?

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to send as many different FCM messages as users. You cannot have one message that is different for different users!

Comment: yes, I knew it ! and I had done it , but when I send it like that, the notification is always delayed and appears after a few minutes.